# Diff between "return" and "yield" stmts in generators

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

Have a look at the code:

```
def main():
    for p in test1(): print(p)

def test1():
    s = set()
    s.update(range(5))
    for p in s: yield p
    return s
```

Why I got only 0,1,2,3,4? The output should be: 0,1,2,3,4 two times (1 for 'yield' and 1 for 'return')

PS: Python-3.4

Comment: The main part of your question is in the code and not visible as its off to the side.

Comment: Do you understand what `else` on `for` does?  It's explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

Comment: You also yield the actual set in the first function, after you're done yielding all the elements therein. You need to understand that the return is never executed, and even if it is, is never used

Comment: Didn't know that it was possible to put an `else` clause in a `for` loop. Found a [nice blog post](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html) about it.

Comment: @Neftas the other pattern I always used to forget was `try/except/else`, where the `else` clause is only executed if there are no exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A return statement in a Python 3.3+ generator doesn't do what you think it does. The value is not returned to the caller like in a normal function, but added as an attribute on the `StopIteration` exception the generator raises to signal that it is done iterating. The behavior you're seeing in your loop is unrelated.

First, lets understand the loop behavior. This comes down to a simple fact: The loop variable (e.g. `i`) doesn't go out of scope when a `for` loop ends:

```
for i in range(5): # this loop will print 0 through 4
    print(i)

print(i) # this line will print 4 again, since 4 it was the last value assigned to i
```

Your code is doing exactly this. The `else` clause you're using does nothing special, since you never `break` out of the loop. (Neftas's answer explains what an `else` attached to a loop is for.)

As for where the `return` value is going, you can find it if you iterate over your generator manually:

```
gen = test1()
print(next(gen)) # prints 0
print(next(gen)) # prints 1
print(next(gen)) # prints 2
print(next(gen)) # prints 3
print(next(gen)) # prints 4
print(next(gen)) # prints set([0,1,2,3,4]) from the last yield statement
try:
    next(gen)
except StopIteration as e:
    print(e.value) # prints set([0,1,2,3,4]) from the return statement
```

This isn't a very common usage. The usual way of getting at the returned value is by using the result of a `yield from` expression in another generator:

```
def test3():
    print(yield from test1())
```

This is a generator that yields all the same values as `test1`, but it also prints out the value that `test1` returns.

I don't think the `return` idiom is terribly useful in most situations. `yield from` can be very useful in recursive or otherwise complex generators, but I've never found a need to `return` a value from one.

If you want more information about the `yield from` expression and the return value from generators, read [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/), which describes the new features that were added in Python 3.3.

Comment: I just wanted to increase the performance of my app by returning the last part of the 'set' and avoid some mess. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a discussion of `return` in a generator, see Blckknght's answer, this is about the `else` clause in a `for` loop.

I read a [nice article about else clauses in for loops](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html) if you don't like the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

The gist of it is that an `else` clause in a `for` loop is all about completion, rather than about conditionals. Compare:

```
if 1:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

Here, the `else` clause is executed when the comparison falls through.
But:

```
for i in xrange(5):
    if i == 123:
        print "Found it!"
        break
else:
    print "Value not in list"
# output: "Value not in list"
```

Here, the `else` clause gets executed *unless* the flow of execution hits the `break` statement:

```
for i in xrange(5):
    if i == 4:
        print "Found it!"
        break
else:
    print "Value not in list"
# output: "Found it!"
```

If your remove the `break`, both strings will be printed. In your code the flow of execution will always reach the `else` statement, so the code there is run.

Comment: Returning a value from a generator is legal in Python 3.3 and later. It has some (obscure) use when coupled with a `yield from` expression.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks, I didn't know. I cut that part out, but left the rest in case it may prove useful for somebody.